# MVC3 Client-side validation on collection, at least one element with value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation, model-validation

My ViewModel

```
Public Class ViewModel
  <SelectOne()>
  Public Property Collection As List(Of Item)
End Class
```

My Model

```
Public Class Item
  <SelectOneProperty(TargetValue:=True, ErrorMessage:="Select at least one.")>
  Public Property Selected As Boolean
  Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

In my view I'm rendering `ViewModel.Collection` with an Editor Template

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(item) item.Selected)
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(item) item.Value)
```

**Now, what I want, is making sure that at least one checkbox is checked using client-side validation.**

I can achieve this by setting a custom validation attribute on the `Item.Selected` property and registering a new adapter through `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()`

But I feel the attribute should rather be on the `ViewModel.Collection` property as on the server side I am already validating if one of the collection's item has `Selected = True` using this custom validation:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field Or AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple:=False, Inherited:=False)>
Public Class SelectOneAttribute
    Inherits ValidationAttribute

    Protected Overrides Function IsValid(value As Object, validationContext As ValidationContext) As ValidationResult

        Dim list As IList

        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        If TypeOf value Is IEnumerable Then
            list = CType(value, IList)
        Else
            list = New Object() {value}
        End If

        Dim count As Integer = (From item In list
                                From prop In item.GetType().GetProperties()
                                Let attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(RequireOneOrMoreIndicatorAttribute), False)
                                Where attributes.Count > 0
                                From attribute In attributes
                                Where attribute.TargetValue = prop.GetValue(item, Nothing)).Count()
        If count > 0 Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return New ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName))
    End Function
End Class
```

It uses reflection on `SelectOnePropertyAttribute` to find which property to check against:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field Or AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple:=False, Inherited:=False)>
Public Class SelectOnePropertyAttribute
    Inherits ValidationAttribute
    Implements IClientValidatable

    Public Property TargetValue As Object

    Public Sub New(targetValue As Object)
        Me.TargetValue = targetValue
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function IsValid(value As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function GetClientValidationRules(metadata As System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata, context As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext) _
        As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule) _
        Implements System.Web.Mvc.IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules

        Dim rule As New ModelClientValidationRule With {
            .ValidationType = "selectone",
            .ErrorMessage = Me.ErrorMessage
        }

        Return New ModelClientValidationRule() {rule}
    End Function
End Class
```

And this it the client-side validation

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("selectone", function (options) {
    options.rules["selectone"] = {};
    options.messages["selectone"] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("selectone", function (value, element, parameters) {

    var $el = $(element),
        name = $el.attr("name"),
        field = name.replace(/\[.*$/, "").replace(".", "_"),
        attr = name.replace(/^.*\./, ""),
        test = new RegExp(field + "\\[\\d\\]\." + attr);

    var inputs = $("input[id^=" + field + "]:not([disabled]):not([type=hidden])").filter("input[name$=" + attr + "]");

    for(var i = 0; i < this.errorList.length; i++) {
        var name = $(this.errorList[i].element).attr("name");

        // Do not write out the error more than once.
        if (test.test(name)) return true;
    }

    return inputs.length == 0 || inputs.filter(":checked:not([disabled])").val();
});
```

Comment: I am working on a CustomValidation solution for you. I hate VB so it will be in C#. Let me know if that is cool

Comment: Just curious, wouldn't you like to be able to define exactly which check box you want checked on your ViewModel?

Comment: C# is fine. I'd like to be able to set any property/value combination. Not only boolean values.

Comment: I have given the solution..Please check it and let me now..That is help ful to you

Comment: Hey..Please check the answer..Which i have given to you?

Comment: At least reply me..Have you checked it

Comment: I have looked at it. I'm sorry for not answering earlier, I couldn't. It does not fit my needs as I see it now. It is pretty poorly formatted also.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the custom validation that will run on side side but if you want run on client side then you have to create JQuery for that custom validation and then it to your page.

Please refer the below link(s)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2012/04/21/MVC3-Custom-Client-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax.aspx

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I can already achieve client-side and server-side validation. But I feel my solution (using a custom validation attribute and registering an adapter on the Item.Selected property) is not optimal. I really wish the validation attribute was set on the list property rather than on the item's property.

Comment: I understand because validation you have write for the property label so could you please send me your custom validation as well as javascript which you have write then i can provide you the solution.

Comment: The code I have right now works fine. But I really need another solution. One that would apply to the List property only (if it is possible).

Comment: Please share that code then i can work on that give you the correct code

Answer (score 0):

> Make the following Change : -

1.Your ViewModel : -

```
Public Class ViewModel
  <SelectOne()>
  <SelectOneProperty(TargetValue:=True, ErrorMessage:="Select at least one.")>
  Public Property Collection As List(Of Item)
End Class
```

1. My Model : -

   Public Class Item
     Public Property Selected As Boolean
     Public Property Value As String
   End Class
2. On your View Add the following line :

   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ItemCollection)

4.then you will run the view and see the view source then it will

4.And then you will submit the code then it will run  client-side validation. add the debugger and Debug it

5.And then modify the your client side script.
    1.Now you can fetch the value from every check box and check that any of of your check box is selected then submit the form otherwise display the result.

6.Also Make change in SelectOnePropertyAttribute as per your requirement

7.And for Server Side I have done this code on c# : -

[AttributeUsage((AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property), AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class SelectOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public String PropertyName { get; set; }

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object  value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        bool boolVal = false;
        IList list;
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (value.GetType().Name == typeof(List<>).Name || value.GetType().Name == typeof(IList<>).Name)
        {
            list = (IList)value;
        }
        else
        {
            list = new object[] {value};
        }
        if (list.Count<0)
            return null;

        if ((from object item in list let propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties() from info in propertyInfo where String.Equals(info.Name, PropertyName) && (bool)info.GetValue(item) == true select item).Any())
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? It will prevent form submission if there isn't any "myCheckbox" checked...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButtonId').click(function (e) {
        if ($('input[name=myCheckbox]:checked').length == 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please choose at least one checkbox before continuing!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Somewhat. In fact, in the code I submitted in my question, this bit is  added through $.validator.addMethod().